# With what probability one coin is better than the other?

Tags: probability, bernoulli-distribution

Let's say we have two biased coins `C1` and `C2` both having different probability of turning head.

We toss `C1` `n1` times and get `H1` heads, `C2` `n2` times and get `H2` heads. And we find that the ratio of heads for one coin is higher than the other.

What is the probability with which we can say that one coin is better than the other? (better here means higher actual probability of turning head).

Comment: Isn't this a hypothesis testing problem where you have to test whether the estimates of probability of turning up heads for the coins are different.

Comment: If you want a *probability* that one coin is better than another, you can do that with a Bayesian approach; all you need is a prior distribution on the probability. It's a fairly straightforward calculation.

Comment: There is no way by which this data is gonna give you a *probability that one coin is better than the other*. You need additional info/assumptions about a prior distribution for how coins are distributed. Say in a Bayesian approach then the result will differ *a lot* based on your prior assumptions. For instance if those coins are regular coins than they are (a priori) very likely to be equal and you would need a large amount of trials to find decent probability that one is 'better' than the other (because the probability is high that you got two similar coins that accidentally test different)

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Why can I not use the uniform prior for the coins distribution as in my answer below?

Comment: @katosh, you can use the uniform prior when your prior information is truly such that the distribution is uniform. But would you use a similar uniform prior when we have, say, two *regular* coins (of which we know they are unfair, due to small dents etc. but not by much)? We can not *just* plug-in *some* prior information (that has not been based on some good thought). The prior might greatly influence the end result.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I tried to lay out my thought on the prior in my answer.

Comment: @katosh, your answer describes nicely the recipe for finding the posterior distribution when we have a prior distribution (in the form of a beta distribution), however, it remains important to stress that the existence of this mathematical trickery does not make it clear cut how we get to a (posterior) probability. Unless we are able to have a large amount of data (and can allow ourselves to be less accurate) it becomes very difficult to make a fine argument in favor of one particular method. We can not base the result on the data alone, and the stated question should be seen as insufficient.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I agree, that a small sample size $n_1$, $n_2$ will lead to insignificant probabilities close to $0.5$ for any coin to be better. But this value is as exact as you can solve the integral. It is not wrong due to the lack of a more informative prior.

Comment: @katosh, it is as exact as the prior. Say you have coins between p=0.49 and p=0.51. If in such case you use the assumption that the coins are uniform distributed between 0 and 1, then the probabilities that you assign are more like updated bad assumptions rather than updated probabilities. You will too often assign a high probability of being 'better' to the wrong coin. It would be wrong to consider the outcome as 'the' probability for the coin being 'better' than the other. Bad data in = bad results out. In this problem we shouldn't work on solving the math but on solving the knowledge.

Comment: When using uniform distribution as prior then it would be a better practice to report a posterior distribution for the *difference* between the coins. Then it becomes directly clear how good the information (or guess) is based on how wide this distributions is.

Comment: Providing a prior would change the question but it would not make it more or less answerable. The result of my answer calculates the believe that $p_1>p_2$ when no prior is given. We could formulate a stronger believe if we had a prior but that is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: In that way it is stated correctly. It is a 'believe' and this is not so easily equated to a 'probability'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is easy to calculate the probability for making that observation, given the fact the two coins are equal. This can be done by [Fishers exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test). Given these observations

$$
\begin{array} {r|c|c}
 &\text{coin }1 &\text{coin }2 \\
\hline
\text{heads} &H_1 &H_2\\
\hline
\text{tails} &n_1-H_1 &n_2-H_2\\\end{array}
$$

the probability to observe these numbers while the coins are equal given the number of tries $n_1$, $n_2$ and the total amount of heads $H_1+H_2$ is
$$
p(H_1, H_2|n_1, n_2, H_1+H_2) = \frac{(H_1+H_2)!(n_1+n_2-H_1-H_2)!n_1!n_2!}{H_1!H_2!(n_1-H_1)!(n_2-H_2)!(n_1+n_2)!}.
$$

But what you are asking for is the probability that one coin is better.
Since we argue about a believe on how biased the coins are we have to use a **[Bayesian approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference)** to calculate the result. Please note, that in Bayesian inference the term **belief** is modeled as **probability** and the two terms are used interchangeably (s. [Bayesian probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability)). We call the probability that coin $i$ tosses heads $p_i$. The posterior distribution after observation, for this $p_i$ is given by [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem):
$$
f(p_i|H_i,n_i)= \frac{f(H_i|p_i,n_i)f(p_i)}{f(n_i,H_i)}
$$
The probability density function (pdf) $f(H_i|p_i,n_i)$ is given by the Binomial probability, since the individual tries are Bernoulli experiments:
$$
f(H_i|p_i,n_i) = \binom{n_i}{H_i}p_i^{H_i}(1-p_i)^{n_i-H_i}
$$
I **assume** the prior knowledge on $f(p_i)$ is that $p_i$ could lie anywhere between $0$ and $1$ with equal probability, hence $f(p_i) = 1$. So the nominator is $f(H_i|p_i,n_i)f(p_i)= f(H_i|p_i,n_i)$.

In Order to calculate $f(n_i,H_i)$ we use the fact that the integral over a pdf has to be one $\int_0^1f(p|H_i,n_i)\mathrm dp = 1$. So the denominator will be a constant factor to achieve just that. There is a known pdf that differs from the nominator by only a constant factor, which is the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). Hence
$$
f(p_i|H_i,n_i) = \frac{1}{B(H_i+1, n_i-H_i+1)}p_i^{H_i}(1-p_i)^{n_i-H_i}.
$$

The pdf for the pair of probabilities of independent coins is
$$
f(p_1,p_2|H_1,n_1,H_2,n_2) = f(p_1|H_1,n_1)f(p_2|H_2,n_2).
$$

Now we need to integrate this over the cases in which $p_1>p_2$ in order to find out how probable coin $1$ is better then coin $2$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb P(p_1>p_2)
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{p‘_1} f(p‘_1,p‘_2|H_1,n_1,H_2,n_2)\mathrm dp‘_2 \mathrm dp‘_1\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{B(p‘_1;H_2+1,n_2-H_2+1)}{B(H_2+1,n_2-H_2+1)}
f(p‘_1|H_1,n_1)\mathrm dp‘_1
\end{align}$$

I cannot solve this last integral analytically but one can solve it numerically with a computer after plugging in the numbers. $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the beta function and $B(\cdot;\cdot,\cdot)$ is the incomplete beta function. Note that $\mathbb P(p_1=p_2) = 0$ because $p_1$ is a continues variable and never exactly the same as $p_2$.

---

Concerning the prior assumption on $f(p_i)$ and remarks on it: A good alternative to model many believes is to use a beta distribution $Beta(a_i+1,b_i+1)$. This would lead to a final probability
$$
\mathbb P(p_1>p_2) 
=\int_0^1 \frac{B(p‘_1;H_2+1+a_2,n_2-H_2+1+b_2)}{B(H_2+1+a_2,n_2-H_2+1+b_2)}
f(p‘_1|H_1+a_1,n_1+a_1+b_1)\mathrm dp‘_1.
$$
That way one could model a strong bias towards regular coins by large but equal $a_i$, $b_i$. It would be equivalent to tossing the coin $a_i+b_i$ additional times and receiving $a_i$ heads hence equivalent to just having more data. $a_i + b_i$ is the amount of **tosses we would not have to make** if we include this prior.

The OP stated that the two coins are both biased to an unknown degree. So I understood all knowledge has to be inferred from the observations. This is why I opted for an [uninformative prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Uninformative_priors) that dose not bias the result e.g. towards regular coins.

All information can be conveyed in the form of $(H_i, n_i)$ per coin. The lack of an informative prior only means more observations are needed to decide which coin is better with high probability.

---

Here is the code in R that provides a function `P(n1, H1, n2, H2)` $=\mathbb P(p_1>p_2)$ using the uniform prior $f(p_i)=1$:

```r
mp <- function(p1, n1, H1, n2, H2) {
    f1 <- pbeta(p1, H2 + 1, n2 - H2 + 1)
    f2 <- dbeta(p1, H1 + 1, n1 - H1 + 1)
    return(f1 * f2)
}

P <- function(n1, H1, n2, H2) {
    return(integrate(mp, 0, 1, n1, H1, n2, H2))
}
```

You can draw $P(p_1>p_2)$ for different experimental results and fixed $n_1$, $n_2$ e.g. $n_1=n_2=4$ with this code sniped:

```r
library(lattice)
n1 <- 4
n2 <- 4
heads <- expand.grid(H1 = 0:n1, H2 = 0:n2)
heads$P <- apply(heads, 1, function(H) P(n1, H[1], n2, H[2])$value)
levelplot(P ~ H1 + H2, heads, main = "P(p1 > p2)")
```

[image: P(p1 > p2) for n1=n2=4]

You may need to `install.packages("lattice")` first.

One can see, that even with the uniform prior and a small sample size, the probability or believe that one coin is better can become quite solid, when $H_1$ and $H_2$ differ enough. An even smaller relative difference is needed if $n_1$ and $n_2$ are even larger. Here is a plot for $n_1=100$ and $n_2=200$:

[image]

---

Martijn Weterings [suggested](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365789/with-what-probability-one-coin-is-better-than-the-other/365808#comment688225_365789) to calculate the posterior probability distribution for the difference between $p_1$ and $p_2$. This can be done by integrating the pdf of the pair over the set $S(d)=\{(p_1,p_2)\in[0,1]^2|d=|p_1-p_2|\}$:
$$\begin{align}
f(d|H_1,n_1,H_2,n_2)
&= \int_{S(d)}f(p_1,p_2|H_1,n_1,H_2,n_2) \mathrm d\gamma\\
&= \int_0^{1-d} f(p,p+d|H_1,n_1,H_2,n_2) \mathrm dp + \int_d^1 f(p,p-d|H_1,n_1,H_2,n_2) \mathrm dp\\
\end{align}$$

Again, not an integral I can solve analytically but the R code would be:

```r
d1 <- function(p, d, n1, H1, n2, H2) {
    f1 <- dbeta(p, H1 + 1, n1 - H1 + 1)
    f2 <- dbeta(p + d, H2 + 1, n2 - H2 + 1)
    return(f1 * f2)
}

d2 <- function(p, d, n1, H1, n2, H2) {
    f1 <- dbeta(p, H1 + 1, n1 - H1 + 1)
    f2 <- dbeta(p - d, H2 + 1, n2 - H2 + 1)
    return(f1 * f2)
}

fd <- function(d, n1, H1, n2, H2) {
    if (d==1) return(0)
    s1 <- integrate(d1, 0, 1-d, d, n1, H1, n2, H2)
    s2 <- integrate(d2, d, 1, d, n1, H1, n2, H2)
    return(s1$value + s2$value)
}
```

I plotted $f(d|n_1,H_1,n_2,H_2)$ for $n_1=4$, $H_1=3$, $n_2=4$ and all values of $H_2$:

```r
n1 <- 4
n2 <- 4
H1 <- 3
d <- seq(0, 1, length = 500)

get_f <- function(H2) sapply(d, fd, n1, H1, n2, H2)
dat <- sapply(0:n2, get_f)

matplot(d, dat, type = "l", ylab = "Density",
        main = "f(d | 4, 3, 4, H2)")
legend("topright", legend = paste("H2 =", 0:n2),
       col = 1:(n2 + 1), pch = "-")
```

[image]

You can calculate the probability of $|p_1-p_2|$ to be above a value $d$ by `integrate(fd, d, 1, n1, H1, n2, H2)`. Mind that the double application of the numerical integral comes with some numerical error. E.g. `integrate(fd, 0, 1, n1, H1, n2, H2)` should always equal $1$ since $d$ always takes a value between $0$ and $1$. But the result often deviates slightly.

Comment: I don't know the actual value of p1

Comment: I am sorry for my bad notation  but you do not need to plug in a fixed value for $p_1$. The (now changed) $p‘_1$ in the integral is the variable you integrate over. Just like you can integrate $\int_0^1 x^2 \mathrm dx$ without having a fixed value for $x$.

Comment: Fisher's exact test is more specifically about the hypothesis that the coins have the same probability *and* the marginal totals are *fixed*. This is not the case in this coin problem. If you do the test again then you could observe some other total amount of heads.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings in my case, the probability of turning head for a coin is fixed always. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @ThirupathiThangavel the problem with Fisher's test is about the not fixed marginal totals. The exact test model assumes that the probability of heads are the same and fixed, but *also* marginals are fixed before the experiment. That second part is not the case. This gives a different conditional probability for extreme values. Overall the Fisher test will be conservative. The probability of the result given the TRUE hypothesis (ie. fixed and similar probability for heads, but *not* necessarily fixed marginal totals) is smaller than calculated (you get higher p-values).

Comment: I do not suggest to use Fishers test to answer the question about probability. I presented it however as an easy alternative that is typically used to compare two coins. In hypothesis testing you reject the 0-hypothesis (that the coins are equal) if the p-value is small (e.g. below 0.05). I do not understand what you mean about the marginals. The p-value are exact even if column sums differ. (from Wikipdia: *"This remains true even if men enter our sample with different probabilities than women."*) Only if you calculate multiple p-values you will have to adjust for multiple testing.

Comment: It relates to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_tasting_tea
In that experiment you can use Fisher's exact test or the hyper-geometric distribution
You can *not* do this for an experiment with flipping coins.
If you flip the coins each four times then the Fisher's exact test will give $p=2/70$ for the most extreme situation. But this situation (or more extreme) occurs much less often than $2/70$, more precisely $2p^4(1-p)^4$ which is at best $2/256$, thus much more rare.

Comment: "The prior knowlage f(pi) is that pi could lie anywhere between 0 and 1 with equal probability" This should be more clearly labeled an assumption. In the real world, this does not hold.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings How do you like the edit?

Comment: It is still a bit odd to make an introduction with this Fisher's exact test example since the provided probability does not relate to an experiment where this test applies (since the $H_1 + H_2$ is not fixed). But I'd say it is much less disturbing now since at least the statements are correct now. Sorry for having been pedantic. (I do get however what point you are trying to make, that probabilities relate to a distribution over observations and you can easily compute probabilities for observations given a model/hypothesis but not the other way around, unless doing Bayesian analysis)

Answer (score 2):

I've made a numerical simulation with `R`, probably you're looking for an analytical answer, but I thought this could be interesting to share.

```
set.seed(123)
# coin 1
N1 = 20
theta1 = 0.7

toss1 <- rbinom(n = N1, size = 1, prob = theta1)

# coin 2
N2 = 25
theta2 = 0.5

toss2 <- rbinom(n = N2, size = 1, prob = theta2)

# frequency
sum(toss1)/N1 # [1] 0.65
sum(toss2)/N2 # [1] 0.52
```

In this first code, I simply simulate two coin toss. Here you can see of course that it `theta1 > theta2`, then of course the frequency of `H1` will be higher than `H2`. Note the different `N1`,`N2` sizes.

Let's see what we can do with different `thetas`. Note the code is not optimal. At all.

```
simulation <- function(N1, N2, theta1, theta2, nsim = 100) {
  count1 <- count2 <- 0

  for (i in 1:nsim) {
    toss1 <- rbinom(n = N1, size = 1, prob = theta1)
    toss2 <- rbinom(n = N2, size = 1, prob = theta2)

    if (sum(toss1)/N1 > sum(toss2)/N2) {count1 = count1 + 1} 
    #if (sum(toss1)/N1 < sum(toss2)/N2) {count2 = count2 + 1} 
  }

  count1/nsim

}
set.seed(123)
simulation(20, 25, 0.7, 0.5, 100)
#[1] 0.93
```

So 0.93 is the frequency of times (out of a 100) that the first coin had more heads. This seems ok, looking at `theta1` and `theta2` used.

Let's see with two vector of `thetas`.

```
theta1_v <- seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.9, by = 0.1)
theta2_v <- seq(from = 0.9, to = 0.1, by = -0.1)

res_v <- c()
for (i in 1:length(theta1_v)) {

  res <- simulation(1000, 1500, theta1_v[i], theta2_v[i], 100)
  res_v[i] <- res

}

plot(theta1_v, res_v, type = "l")
```

Remember that `res_v` are the frequencies where `H1 > H2`, out of 100 simulations.

[image]

So as `theta1` increases, then the probability of `H1` being higher increases, of course.

I've done some other simulations and it seems that the sizes `N1`,`N2` are less important.

If you're familiar with `R` you can use this code to shed some light on the problem. I'm aware this is not a complete analysis, and it can be improved.

Comment: Interesting how `res_v` changes continuously when the thetas meet. I understood the question as it was asking about the coins intrinsic bias after making just a single observation. You seem to answer what observations one would make after knowing the bias.